# Teamviewer and Virtualbox issue: some keys don't work

Tags: virtualbox, teamviewer

I use Teamviewer on a laptop to connect to a desktop computer running Debian Linux. On this desktop computer I run Windows inside a VirtualBox VM. 
I have no problems interacting directly with Linux, but when I try to interact with Windows inside Virtualbox, some keys simply don't work! (e.g. period, "@", quotes).

Is there something I can do to make the full keyboard of my laptop work correctly with the Virtualbox VM inside the remote host?

Specs:

- The remote host machine is an Intel i7 running Debian squeezy (64 bit)
- I'm using Teamviewer 7, on both the host machine and the laptop

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution (a dumb one by the way): I installed Teamviewer on the VM.

Anyway, it works

Answer (score 0):

In teamviewer enable Send Key Combinations under Actions.

Comment: First, the question has already been answered, and second, a little more explanation can help turn a comment into an answer, and that is a good thing here,